# Reports in SQL from ytd and 2 years back

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I would like to make a sale report with the information of year to date and two years back all in the same report. I have this query as example selecting year 2007, but i need to do year to day , then 2012,2011,2010. in the same report.
any idea? thanks

I have select , field names,
from tables,
where DocDate > = '2007-01-01'  and DocDate <='2007-12-31'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSalesReport 
    @Year AS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateFrom AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @DateTo AS DATETIME

    SET @DateFrom = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Year)+'0101')
    SET @DateTo = GETDATE()

    select field names 
    from tables
    where DocDate > = @DateFrom and DocDate <=@DateTo

    SET @DateFrom = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Year-1)+'0101')
    SET @DateTo = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Year-1)+'1231')

    select field names 
    from tables
    where DocDate > = @DateFrom and DocDate <=@DateTo


    SET @DateFrom = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Year-2)+'0101')
    SET @DateTo = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Year-2)+'1231')

    select field names 
    from tables
    where DocDate > = @DateFrom and DocDate <=@DateTo
END
```

Comment: when i declare the variable the i put the days that i would like in the fiel @datefrom?

Comment: @DateFrom is your start date and DateTo your end date.

Comment: I will like to use one year in a subquery how can i make the set fuction work in the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

To do year to date just put 'WHERE DocDate >= 2013-01-01'

For each year make a WHERE condition 'WHERE DocDate >= 2012-01-01 and DocDate <= 2012-12-12'

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the data from current year-to-date PLUS past 2-3 years (title shows 2, post showing 3)

```
select
      YEAR(DocDate) as EachYear,
      field names
   from 
      tables
   where 
      DocDate > = '2007-01-01'
   order by
      EachYear DESC
```

Now, if you are trying to some aggregations, such as annual sales counts, totals, etc, you would apply a GROUP BY for the "EachYear" computed column

```
select
      YEAR(DocDate) as EachYear,
      sum( someTable.orderAmt ) as TotalOrdered,
      count(*) as NumberOrders,
      avg( someTable.OrderAmt ) as AvgOrder
   from 
      tables
   where 
      DocDate > = '2007-01-01'
   GROUP BY
      Year(DocDate)
   order by
      Year(DocDate) DESC
```